# Как остановить скрипт js и запустить новый?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, javascript

```
<script>
    var second=20;
    function time(){
          if(second<=9){second="0" + second;}
          if(document.getElementById){t.innerHTML=second;}

          if(second==00){return false;}
          second--;
          setTimeout("time()", 1000);
        }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function loadLike() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{% url 'bet_up' pk %}',
            data: { get_param: 'value'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                time();
                $('#result').text('Цена ' + data.price);
                $('#prodan').text('Продукт будет продан ' + data.latest_user);
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<button id="like" onclick="loadLike()">Ставка</button>
```

При onclick запускается функция loadlike, которая в себя включает функцию time(). Суть в том, что начинает тикать время в обратном направлении (20 секунд), и при нажатии снова на Ставку скрипт должен сбрасываться, и таймер должен идти с самого начала. Я так понял, нужно прервать time() и запустить снова. Я не знаю, как это реализовать, в этом и вопрос. В моем случае таймер не сбрасывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам такой вариант http://jsfiddle.net/zdLLeupt/

Вместо setTimeout используем setInterval и сделаем код более понятным.

Comment: Спасибо, идеально!)

Answer (score 3):

Первым делом очищаете тайм-аут:

```
timerId = setTimeout(time, 1000);//Устанавливаем таймер
clearTimeout(timerId); //Отменяем таймаут
```

Ну и параллельно еще и сбрасываете счетчик на начальное состояние:

```
second = 20;
```